# SKAction scaleXTo:-1

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I am trying to mirror my SKSpriteNode using `SKAction *mirrorDirection  = [SKAction scaleXTo:-1 y:1 duration:0.0];` but every time I do, the sprite's physics body seems to get messed up and it drops off the screen. I have several objects (floors) beneath the sprite and it falls through all of them as if they are not there.

This only happens when I mirror the sprite. Anyone know how to fix this?

**Update:**
Reseting the physics body as one answer suggested unfortunately did not fix the problem. It appears that only the contact part of the physics body malfunctions. Gravity still has an effect as the little guy drops like a rock.

I also tried to reset by again `self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width, self.size.height)];`

right after the `self.xScale = -1;` but this also did not fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding your mirrored node as a child of a regular SKNode and setting the physics body on the SKNode instead of the negatively scaled node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your mirror-able node as a child of some regular SKNode and set the physics body on this parent node instead of the negatively scaled node.

Comment: I did a test project and this method seems to work. Albeit a tedious one to code. Hopefully Apple will remedy this in a future update. Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix this but I would like to suggest one way you could create a mirrored sprite.

To achieve this set the x or y scale of your sprite node to -1.  Then use the SKView method  [textureFromNode:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKView/textureFromNode%3a) to create a texture from this mirrored node.

You can then use this texture to create a new sprite node that is mirrored but doesn't require any negative scaling.

Comment: This option will probably work on simple sprites but I have a bunch of animations preloaded... walk, run, jump, etc... Creating a new sprite unfortunately causes a noticeable delay in game flow.

Comment: Are you worried about the generation of the texture causing lag or just losing your place in the animation causing jumpiness?  I would recommend doing any texture generation during your load sequence and reusing this texture which should mitigate the first problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an SKAction, just set it directly to the SKSpriteNode's xScale property.

```
self.yourSprite.xScale = -1;
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion but unfortunately the little guy still drops like a rock.

Answer (score 0):

Roecrew is right about setting the xScale property directly. I would suggest you try this:

```
node.xScale = -1;
node.physicsBody = node.physicsBody;
```

You will need to 'reset' the physicsBody each time you change the xScale property.

The xScale issue with physicsBody is a bug in SpriteKit, but I was able to 'retain' the physicsBody using the second line.

Comment: Also tried your suggestion with the physics body reset but no joy.

Comment: The physicsBody has to be initialized normally at least once for this to work.

Comment: As I said, everything works peachy with no issues. The problem starts as soon as I mirror the sprite.

Comment: @sangony Are you making a platform game? If so, have you thought about using tmx mapping?

Comment: I am using the app Tiled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm meeting the problem exactly like yours. I spent about 2 hours to figure it out.

Just init your physicsBody after you scaleX, i dont know why but i had correct this issue by doing this way.

```
walkRight   = [SKAction sequence:@[resetDirection,[SKAction runBlock:^{
            [self changePhysicsDirectionRight];
        }],[SKAction repeatActionForever: walk]]];
walkLeft   = [SKAction sequence:@[mirrorDirection,[SKAction runBlock:^{
            [self changePhysicsDirectionLeft];
        }],[SKAction repeatActionForever: walk]]];
```

walkRight and walkLeft is my action when changing direction, and resetDirection and mirrorDirection is exactly the action i used to scaleXTo:1 and scaleXTo:1

So after i scaleXTo i use a method call changePhysicsDirectionRight to re-init my physicBody like

```
- (void)changePhysicsDirectionRight{
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width,self.size.height)];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = guyCategory;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask   = 0;
}
```

Remember to re-assign all your category and everything like you init before.

I hope someone pro at spritekit can tell me the reason why ....