# SKSpritenode, parent and child node relationship

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am trying to make a parent and child sprite node and add the texture/animation and xScale to the child and "physicsBody" to the parent (parent as a wrapper that holds only to the physics body?)

at the moment I've only got `SKSpritenode *arrowParentNode;` which gives me the following error:

```
"Attempted to add nil node to parent".
```

Bellow is the code. I don't know what goes in the parent if the texture and animation is on the child? 
I am not sure if I'm doing this right at all, could anyone please explain?

I did also try `_arrowParentNode = [ self arrowChildNode ];`
Which gave me the following error after re entering the scene:

```
Attempted to add a SKNode which already has a parent.
```

It didn't also solve the problem I had initially which was similar to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702763/skaction-scalexto-1).

Thanks in advance.

```
SKSpritenode *arrowParentNode;
.
..
...

-(void) arrowParentNode {

   // _arrowParentNode = [ ? ] //  <-- what goes in here if the textures are in within the child? 
    _arrowParentNode.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.2, 0.75);
    _arrowParentNode.physicsBody=[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_brick.size];
    _arrowParentNode.physicsBody.dynamic =NO;
    _arrowParentNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity=YES;
    _arrowParentNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = pengCategory;
    _arrowParentNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = chickenCategory;
    [self addChild:_arrowParentNode];

}

- (SKSpriteNode *) arrowChildNode {
   SKSpritenode * arrowTexture = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:ARROW_SPR_ARROW0001];

    SKAction *sharkOCAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:ARROW_ANIM_BALL timePerFrame:0.02];

    SKAction *scaleBall = [SKAction scaleTo:-1 duration:0];

    [_arrowParentNode addChild:_arrowTexture];

    return _arrowTexture;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a plain SKNode and assign it:

```
_arrowParentNode = [SKNode node];
```

Also change the variable declaration from SKSpriteNode to:

```
SKNode* _arrowParentNode;
```